# Pandas: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

Seen a couple of answers to the general question, and I've used some of the solutions suggested, but still getting stuck.

I have the following code:

```
name = ['Sepal-length', 'Sepal-width', 'Petal-length', 'Petal-width', 'Class']
iris_ds = pd.read_csv(url, names=name)

cols=iris_ds.columns.drop('Class')
iris_ds[cols]=iris_ds[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

.......

iris_ds['Sepal-area'] = iris_ds.eval('Sepal-width' * 'Sepal-length')  
print(iris_ds.head(20))
```

However, when I run the script for the second section, I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Iris_Data_set1.py", line
>   67, in 
>       iris_ds['Petal-area'] = iris_ds.eval('Petal-width' * 'Petal-length') TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type
>   'str'

The data types are as follows:

> Sepal-length    float64
>
> Sepal-width     float64
>
> Petal-length    float64
>
> Petal-width     float64
>
> Class            object
>
> dtype: object

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue, so that I can do the multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't just do:

```
iris_ds['Sepal-area'] = iris_ds.Sepal-width * iris_ds.Sepal-length
```

I think there might be 2 problems though. You probably shouldn't be using `Sepal-length` as a column name and instead should use `Sepal_length` (and apply this to your other variables), making the answer:

```
iris_ds['Sepal_area'] = iris_ds.Sepal_width * iris_ds.Sepal_length
```

Comment: @Clauric just for future reference, in general it is a bad idea to name variables with a `-` in them because python interprets it as the mathematical symbol for subtraction, instead of part of a variable name. It's recommended to use `_` instead. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables